# Getting ClassNotFoundExcpetion: oracle.sql.Array error during compiling report

Tags: jasper-reports

I would be very much appreciable, if any one can found the solution for the below question.

I am getting error while compiling the JasperReports's report the error was `"ClassNotFoundException : oracle.sql.ARRAY not found by net.sf.jasperstudion 6.0"`.

[image]

Comment: You should add jar file with this class to cp

Comment: what kind jar file should I add? and how to add jar for specific project or jasper class path? could please suggest me?

Comment: Can you post the small sample to reproduce your issue?